# How many days could google updates my pages titles and contents order

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-penguin-algorithm

After Google's penguin 2.0 - *I call it dracula* - my website has lost about 30% or more of its traffic. The following screen shot from my Google's webmaster tools account should demonstrate the disaster:

[image]

I decided to change the title tag of some of its pages - they are 6236 pages exactly - and rearrange the order of those pages contents. I have done this from more 4 days ago and I does not able to see the new title tag in Google's search results.

From [this question's answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31089/how-many-days-would-update-if-i-modify-page-metatitle-and-metadescription) on this community they said on Google it may take couple of days! **I need to know if there is something else I have to consider? or what's the issue that makes Google delay updating my website's regarded pages modification?**

Comment: It appears to me that you are just asking for a second opinion about the answer to your linked question.    As far as I can tell, it is exactly the same question otherwise.

Comment: You lost only 30% of the traffic? Consider yourself lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On webmaster tools, submitting a new sitemap and/or manually fetching pages can help. (I see you have a lot of pages though)

By the size of your site, I would say it gets crawled somewhat quickly so it should not take that long for updates to display.

I'll refrain from giving a date, I don't think anyone can be sure. But they will change eventually, that's for sure.

Comment: I already have resubmitted my existent sitemap. The sitemap is dynamically changed. However, the regarded 6236 pages are the have the same urls in this sitemap.
However, do you mean that it is just a matter of time?

Comment: As long as those pages are re-crawled it should be